# c++ Multidimensional array wont initialize

Tags: c++

I have been trying to get this to work correctly; however it seems I can not figure this out. I am trying to get a game board to initialize correctly but it keeps saying that `<error reading characters of string>`.

```
using namespace std;

int main()
{

    board show;
    show.init();
    show.printing();

}


class board {

public:
    void init(){

        string Board[8][9] = {
            { "C56", "C15", "C21", "C62", "C11", "C62", "C21", "C15", "C56" },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
            { "C56", "C15", "C21", "C62", "C11", "C62", "C21", "C15", "C56" },
        };
    }

    void printing(){

        string character = "*";

        int position[2] = { 2, 2 };
        // Draw the grid once
        for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
            for (int j = 0; j < 9; j++){
                if (i == position[0] && j == position[1])
                    cout << character;
                else
                    cout <<  Board[8][9];
                cout << " ";
            }
            cout << endl;
        }
    }

private:
    string Board[8][9];
};
```

Comment: `cout <<  Board[8][9];` uses two invalid indices. You probably mistyped `cout << Board[i][j];`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's so easy: you have the half solution:
just use for loop to copy values

```
void A::init()
{
    string Board[8][9] = {
        { "C56", "C15", "C21", "C62", "C11", "C62", "C21", "C15", "C56" },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 ", " 0 " },
        { "C56", "C15", "C21", "C62", "C11", "C62", "C21", "C15", "C56" },
    };

    for(int i(0); i < 8; i++)
    {
        for(int j(0); j < 9; j++)
            this->Board[i][j] = Board[i][j];        
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the `init` method you created a new, **local variable**. You are not referring to your **instance variable**, therefore in `printing` method the variable is not initialized.

Instead of

```
string Board[8][9] = // ... initialization code
```

you should write

```
this->Board = // ... initialization code
```

or just

```
Board = // ... initialization code
```

You can read more about variable types [here](http://www.programmerinterview.com/index.php/c-cplusplus/whats-the-difference-between-a-class-variable-and-an-instance-variable/).

Comment: The use of `this` is not required (it is implied).  But if you are going to use it, it is a pointer not a reference.

Comment: @Peter true, too much Java lately (;

Comment: My condolences.

Comment: @Jezer Thank you, now I am getting the error: Expression  must be a modifiable lvalue. Any tips to fix that?

Comment: You can't assign to arrays.

Comment: C-style arrays have weird syntax requirements, it would make life easier to use `array<array<string, 9>, 8>`. Looks ugly at first but simplifies the rest of the code.